# Advantages and uses of Nintex workflow in sharepoint 2013 over designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I want to implement nintex workflow in my sharepoint 2013 site with infopath 
But first need to understand what are advantages of nintex workflow over designer workflow, also can we do some coding in this?

Answer (score 0):

Nintex can simplify the process of creating a workflow significantly as it is way more 'visual' than SPD workflows (drag and drop with pretty icons etc.).You also create workflows directly in the browser and dont need any additional software on your PC. I'm pretty sure Nintex allows for far greater flexibility when it comes to the kinds of logic you can use within your workflows i.e - While loops etc...